# How to design "overflowing" border lines of css <div>?

Tags: html, css, border, box

Just getting into css and, though trying different approaches, I don't manage to design a content box with the borders I have in mind. It should look something like this:

[image: Box as desired]

In words: The borders should cross each other and continue for some maybe 30px, maybe we can call it overflow. Resulting in crosses at all four edges.

I have tried to design small cubic boxes each at every edge, and it kinda works. But I find it very hard to include them in my concept of responsiveness, as they don't shrink at the same rate that the actual box (lets call it `<box>`) does. The `<box>` has side margins in percent, so when the page is being scaled down, the small boxes `<sbox>` are in my way and preventing the margins of `<box>` from reaching out all the way to the frames borders.

Any ideas on how to make that one more elegant?

Comment: i will try to do something. i think I know what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example without pseudo classes

```css
.outer{
  height: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
}

.content{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.innerContent{
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
}

.borderLeftRight{
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer borderLeftRight"></div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="innerContent borderLeftRight">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer borderLeftRight"></div>
```

Comment: I like this one as it is adapting to the page's width! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @M.Beit If you look at my answer the second part does this and a lot better. No need for all of these HTML elements. Just remove the `div` width and it will be the same, the width was only there for the example.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the help of `before` and `after` pseudo classes.

```css
* { box-sizing:border-box; }
.box { padding:20px; width:100px; height:100px;  position:relative;  border-left:2px solid #000; border-right:2px solid #000;  }

.box::after { position:absolute; top:5px; left:-7px; background:#000; width:110px; height:2px; content:"";}

.box::before { position:absolute; bottom:5px; left:-7px; background:#000; width:110px; height:2px; content:"";}
```

```html
    <div class="box">
      Content
    </div>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXgwJB)

Answer (score 0):

Somebody already did something similar. I think the most elegant way is with pseudo selectors `:before` & `:after`. I feel you should do it in this way and not with wrappers. Most important things are setting your element's `position` to `relative` and then before and after selectors position to `absolute`. Then fiddle with `border` and `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` properties.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2em;
}
.box:after,
.box:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}
.box:after {
  border-top: 1px solid #f00;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
}
.box:before {
  border-left: 1px solid #f00;
  border-right: 1px solid #f00;
  left: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  text inside
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going to put this up here to show you can do this using a single pseudo element.

### Fixed width

You will have to set the width and height for it, can get around this using `calc` but its support isn't amazing yet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin: 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 240px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Testing</div>
```

---

### Auto width

Example using `calc`, this will work with any size of text.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin: 100px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% + 40px);
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```